# How to find which version of TensorFlow is installed in my system?

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, command-line, version

I need to find which version of TensorFlow I have installed. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 Long Term Support.

Comment: To retreive the summary (incl. version of package) try: `pip show [package name]`, eg: `pip show tensorflow`, `pip show numpy` etc.

Comment: Simply `print(tf.__version__)`

Comment: Anyone knowing the difference between `tf.__version__` and `tf.version.VERSION`? My 0.12.0 installation doesn't support latter.

Comment: relevant TensorFlow 2.x API docs (`tf.version.VERSION` is a v2.0 API): https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/version

Answer (score 542, accepted):

This depends on how you installed TensorFlow. I am going to use the same headings used by [TensorFlow's installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#download-and-setup) to structure this answer.

---

### Pip installation

Run:

```
python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'  # for Python 2
python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'  # for Python 3
```

Note that `python` is symlinked to `/usr/bin/python3` in some Linux distributions, so use `python` instead of `python3` in these cases.

`pip list | grep tensorflow` for Python 2 or `pip3 list | grep tensorflow` for Python 3 will also show the version of Tensorflow installed.

---

### Virtualenv installation

Run:

```
python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'  # for both Python 2 and Python 3
```

`pip list | grep tensorflow` will also show the version of Tensorflow installed.

For example, I have installed TensorFlow 0.9.0 in a `virtualenv` for Python 3. So, I get:

```
$ python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
0.9.0

$ pip list | grep tensorflow
tensorflow (0.9.0)
```

Comment: and if you are building from source, your version is commit hash from `git rev-parse HEAD`

Comment: Got ```'module' object has no attribute '__version__'``` when ```python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'```

Comment: @user3768495 Hmm, interesting, let me test that later. Meanwhile, the `pip list` way should work if you used `pip` for installation.

Comment: ```pip list | grep tensorflow``` worked tho. My version is 0.5.0. Maybe it's toooo old to have the '__version__' attribute?

Comment: @user3768495 If you installed Tensorflow with VirtualEnv you need to activate the environment and that must be done for any new console you open (source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate). Once you do that you can retrieve your tensorflow version (pip list | grep tensorflow)

Comment: @Nestor Urquiza do you mean anaconda console under Linux ?

Comment: for Windows CMD you need to use double quote `"` instead of `'`: `python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)"`

Comment: I tried both pip and python, i.e. `pip list | grep tensorflow` and `python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'`. But these two commands give me two different outputs. For pip, it shows `tensorflow 1.12.0`. For python, it shows `1.10.0`. Right before using two two commands to check the version, I used `pip install tensorflow=1.10.0`. Before running this install command, I believe my system was installed with 1.12.0. But, how come after running this install command, could these two version checking commands give different answers? Or, did I miss anything there?

Comment: `py -3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'` worked in my case.

Comment: [jalal@goku examples]$ python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__'

Answer (score 130):

Almost every normal package in python assigns the variable `.__version__` to the current version. So if you want to find the version of some package you can do the following

```
import a
a.__version__
```

For tensorflow it will be

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.version.VERSION
```

For old versions of tensorflow (below 0.10), use `tf.__version__`

Comment: tf.VERSION doesn't work for TF2.0. However, tf.__version__ works fine.

Comment: @apatsekin Fot TF2.0, use `tf.version.VERSION`

Comment: I've installed 'tensorflow-cpu==2.4.1' on my venv and opened jupyter notebook after activating venv. When I do "!pip freeze" it show tensorflow-cpu==2.4.1 correctly however when I run tf.__version__ it tells me I have version 2.7.0.

Comment: looks like even for TF2.0 both works for me, tf.__version__ as well as tf.version.VERSION

Answer (score 84):

If you have installed via pip, just run the following

```
$ pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.5.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
```

Comment: `pip show tensorflow-gpu` for GPU version. Better yet, just do `pip list | grep tensorflow`.

Comment: This is a brilliant command to get summary for any python package!

Comment: I loved this one

Comment: Fun fact: I just realized why this package is called tensorflow thanks to your answer!

Answer (score 34):

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.VERSION)
```

Comment: Thank you, Bilal. This works for versions older than 1.0

Comment: print() with parentheses is a python3 thing, not necessary for python2.

Answer (score 24):

For python 3.6.2:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.version.VERSION)
```

Comment: print (tf.__version__) works in tf2.0 rc (py 3.7.4)

Answer (score 20):

If you're using anaconda distribution of Python,

```
$ conda list | grep tensorflow
tensorflow    1.0.0       py35_0    conda-forge
```

To check it using Jupyter Notebook (IPython Notebook)

```
In [1]: import tensorflow as tf
In [2]: tf.__version__
Out[2]: '1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 11):

For knowing any version of the python library then if your library is installed using the pip then use the following command.

```
pip show tensorflow
```

The Output of the above command will be shown below:-

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.3.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Requires: astunparse, wheel, keras-preprocessing, gast, tensorflow-estimator, opt-einsum, tensorboard, protobuf, absl-py, six, wrapt, termcolor, numpy, grpcio, scipy, google-pasta, h5py
Required-by: fancyimpute
```

Answer (score 9):

I installed the Tensorflow 0.12rc from source, and the following command gives me the version info:

```
python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'  # for Python 2
python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'  # for Python 3
```

The following figure shows the output:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

To get more information about tensorflow and its options you can use below command:

```
>> import tensorflow as tf
>> help(tf)
```

Comment: I get python3.6 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; help(tf)'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 6):

On Latest TensorFlow release **1.14.0**

> tf.VERSION

is deprecated, instead of this use

> tf.version.VERSION

**ERROR:**

```
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
The name tf.VERSION is deprecated. Please use tf.version.VERSION instead.
```

Answer (score 5):

Easily get KERAS and TENSORFLOW version number -->
Run this command in terminal:

[username@usrnm:~] python3

`>>import keras; print(keras.__version__)`

`Using TensorFlow backend.`

`2.2.4`

`>>import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)`

1.12.0

Answer (score 4):

The tensorflow version can be checked either on terminal or console or in any IDE editer as well (like Spyder or Jupyter notebook, etc)

Simple command to check version:

```
(py36) C:\WINDOWS\system32>python
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)

>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.__version__
'1.13.1'
```

Answer (score 4):

Another variation, i guess :P

```
python3 -c 'print(__import__("tensorflow").__version__)'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'  # for Python 2
python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'  # for Python 3
```

Here -c represents program passed in as string (terminates option list)

Answer (score 3):

Tensorflow version in Jupyter Notebook:-

```
!pip list | grep tensorflow
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have TensorFlow 2.x:

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))

Comment: Why provide a partial answer to a 4 y/o question that already has multiple answers with very good acceptance? Does this provide any new knowledge?

Comment: @amitai, all packages and tools upgrade, and most of the time, errors are coming back. Old correct solutions may not work today.

Answer (score 3):

**For Windows cmd**

```
pip list | FINDSTR tensorflow
OR
pip show tensorflow
```

**For Linux**

```
pip list | grep tensorflow
OR
pip show tensorflow
```

Answer (score 3):

The version of **Tensorflow** can simply be checked on **jupyter notebook** using the following simple steps.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)  # for Python 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody is suggesting this way, you can do the following in the cmd if you installed the package via pip

```
pip show tensorflow
```

Answer (score -1):

Printing python version in human readable format

```
python -c 'import sys; print(".".join(map(str, sys.version_info[:3])))'
```