# How do I find out the version of TensorFlow on my computer?

Tags: tensorflow

What's the command to find out the version of TensorFlow on my computer? I installed TensorFlow on my computer some time ago and want to make sure that I have the latest version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find which version of TensorFlow is installed in my system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549253/how-to-find-which-version-of-tensorflow-is-installed-in-my-system)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```

Comment: Something you might run into doing this is an error that says "ImportError: cannot import name pywrap_tensorflow". You're likely just running Python from the Tensorflow directory. Just switch to a different directory, and it should work.

Comment: Can we find out if the GPU/CPU version is installed?

Answer (score 15):

```
pip list | grep tensorflow
```

You can find the version of any installed library by replacing 'tensorflow' with the library name.

Answer (score 10):

```
$ pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.5.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ source activate tensorflow
$ pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.9.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
```

Comment: Welcome to posting on Stack Overflow. Thanks for your answer. But please try to refrain from making code only (or command only) answers. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 3):

Use the below code In jupyter-Notebook/Pycharm to check the tensorflow version.

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.version.VERSION)
```

Comment: This also works when I open python 3.8 in terminal on Ubuntu 18.04 with tensorflow version 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
pip freeze|grep tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
$ import tensorflow as tf
$ tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()
True
$ tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None)
False
```