# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'version'

Tags: tensorflow2.0

Can someone please help, why am I getting this error `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'version'` ? ver installed TF2.0.0.rc0

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

# TensorFlow and tf.keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Helper libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(tf.version)
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You need to modify your last statement as `print(tf.__version__)` instead of `print(tf.version)` as the attribute name is `__version__` rather than version. There are two leading and trailing underscores.

Comment: there are two leading and trailing underscores. If you still get any error please post it too.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'version'

Comment: version is not the attribute, please include underscores too

Comment: Duplicate of   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024493/how-do-i-find-out-the-version-of-tensorflow-on-my-computer