# How to fix AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'keras'?

Tags: tensorflow, module, keras, attributes, attributeerror

I'm following a basic tensorflow tutorial (to recognize the 28x28 pixel handwritten digits 0-9), but when I run these two lines:

```
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
```

I get the error message

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'keras'

I've looked at posts where people have similar questions, and it seems the answers are usually to update your tensorflow and keras version, but I think I did that already, and this error message is still appearing. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You probably want to see your file name. I was looking at literally EVERYTHING to find what was causing it, and it turned out I named my file tensorboard.py. Don't name your files tensorflow.py or tensorboard.py or any other module names in general

Answer (score -2):

I think you have typo there.
Should change this line:

`mnist = tf.kera.datasets.mnist`

to:

`mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist`

Notice that I change `kera` to `keras`

Comment: oh that was my bad! I just fixed that and now it is giving me the same error (but this time with 'keras':  "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'keras' "

Comment: What is your tensorflow version? You can check using this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549253/how-to-find-which-version-of-tensorflow-is-installed-in-my-system